# I'm having this error with pycaret: module 'xgboost' has no attribute '__version__'

Tags: python-3.x, pycaret

File ~\mlenv\lib\site-packages\pycaret\containers\models\regression.py:1448, in XGBRegressorContainer.**init**(self, globals_dict)
1445     self.active = False
1446     return
-> 1448 if version.parse(xgboost.**version**) < version.parse("1.1.0"):
1449     logger.warning(
1450         f"Wrong xgboost version. Expected xgboost>=1.1.0, got xgboost=={xgboost.**version**}"
1451     )
1452     self.active = False

AttributeError: module 'xgboost' has no attribute '**version**'

#pycaret.**version** = 2.3.10

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Solved. Just created a new venv.

Answer (score 0):

Just created a new venv and solved!